# Php mvc -link redirection issue

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, model-view-controller

I have developed a web application using php (custom MVC). The web app works fine on the localhost but not on godaddy server.

I have written redirect function as following:

```
public function redirect($controllerName, $action, $params=null) {  

    if($controllerName){
        $link = Constant::$APP_URL . "/" . $controllerName. "/" . $action;      }else{          $link = Constant::$APP_URL  . "/" . $action;        }

    if($params != null) {
        $link .= "?" . http_build_query($params);
    }
    header("Location:" . $link);
    exit;
}
```

Take the following example:

The following on local server works, when I try to login:

https://localhost/project/login

If I type the same on my server, it does not work & redirects me to the following link:

https://example.com/login/login

"login" is a function in one of the controllers.

Any ideas?

My .htaccess file looks like:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule .* index.php [L,QSA]
```

Comment: I removed extra spaces after the php end tags in a few files. That also did not help. I read somewhere, so thought might update here

Comment: Hi everyone, I am still not sure why this problem occurred. But I had another old copy of my project, so started using the same. Things are fine now. If I get an accurate answer, I shall update here. Thankyou!

Answer (score 0):

hey could you please provide us with the error report from cpanel. if you go into your cpanel on godaddy then go to error log it should show a report at the specific time of action. like when the button pushed. if you have javascript as well and nothing shows up(which i doubt) also check google by right clicking and going inspect element. this will give more info for what is actually going on. from there we could source a solution or you might even be able to google possible solutions before you need to ask.

Comment: I did inspect element & got following errors: `Using //@ to indicate sourceMappingURL pragmas is deprecated. Use //# instead` `Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated.  Use defaultPrevented instead.`